how to in powershell get icinga web 2 data
I have a script that gets the "icinga web 2" html page form
This script was created by the firefox developer console. This script only works in powreshell when a firefox session is active. When I log out, the script stops working. Return error 403 (Access Denied).
I do not know where the problem is. I suspect. I suspect it is related to sessionId, windowId and CSRFToken.
Firefox already has the token set in the logon dialog when it sends the post command. But I don't know how to get the token before logging in.
Maybe I'm going about it completely wrong? I say up front that our icinga does not have an api (v1). This is forbidden.
Do you know how to log in to icingaweb2 correctly and get html data? (Or is there some other easier way?)
$dnsName   = "icinga2.mySite.com"
$baseUri   = "https://" + $dnsName
$logonUri  = $baseURI + "/icingaweb2/authentication/login"
$dataUri   = $baseURI + "/icingaweb2/monitoring/list/services?sort=service_state&dir=desc&service_state%3E0&limit=500&showCompact=1"
$uName     = "myUserName"
$uPwd      = "myPassword"
#$csrfToken = "myToken"


$session = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_chc", "1", "/", "$($dnsName)")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("icingaweb2-session", "1721822041", "/", "$($dnsName)")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("Icingaweb2", "mmlmngu2ncr4u94ncbboe3hka9", "/", "$($dnsName)")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("icingaweb2-tzo", "7200-1", "/", "$($dnsName)")))
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "$($logonUri)" `
-Method POST `
-WebSession $session `
-UserAgent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0" `
-Headers @{
"Accept" = "*/*"
  "Accept-Language" = "cs,sk;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3"
  "Accept-Encoding" = "gzip, deflate, br, zstd"
  "X-Icinga-Accept" = "text/html"
  "X-Icinga-Container" = "layout"
  "X-Icinga-WindowId" = "qboktawylfrj"
  "X-Requested-With" = "XMLHttpRequest"
  "Origin" = "$($baseUri)"
  "Referer" = "$($logonUri)"
  "Sec-Fetch-Dest" = "empty"
  "Sec-Fetch-Mode" = "cors"
  "Sec-Fetch-Site" = "same-origin"
  "Priority" = "u=0"
} `
-ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" `
-Body "username=$($uName)&password=$($uPwd)&rememberme=0&redirect=&formUID=form_login&CSRFToken=65513382e85125%7C52db29ddf2b7e77ca4253a791b6da1236c4d83787e2988d1bcd40a482xe&btn_submit=Login"




$session = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("icingaweb2-session", "1721823545", "/", "$($dnsName)")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("Icingaweb2", "5s2f849efld37coa0fgbpcimms", "/", "$($dnsName)")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("icingaweb2-tzo", "7200-1", "/", "$($dnsName)")))
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "$($dataUri)" `
-WebSession $session `
-UserAgent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0" `
-Headers @{
"Accept" = "*/*"
  "Accept-Language" = "cs,sk;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3"
  "Accept-Encoding" = "gzip, deflate, br, zstd"
  "X-Icinga-Accept" = "text/html"
  "X-Icinga-Container" = "ciu_1"
  "X-Icinga-WindowId" = "qboktawylfrj"
  "X-Requested-With" = "XMLHttpRequest"
  "Referer" = "$($baseUri)/icingaweb2/dashboard"
  "Sec-Fetch-Dest" = "empty"
  "Sec-Fetch-Mode" = "cors"
  "Sec-Fetch-Site" = "same-origin"
} `
-ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"


$result.rawcontent
$result.rawcontent | out-file C:\pathToMyData\icinga.data.html

